# User-unhandled exception after upgrading TargetFrameworkVersion from 3.5 to 4.5

Tags: c#, .net

We are developing an existing application currently targeting .NET Framework 3.5. In the new version, the application should run on .NET 4.5. For testing, I upgraded the projects to use .NET Framework 4.5.

First it seemed that everything is working correctly. The application (WinForm) ran as expected. Nothing happens when I start the executable directly and everything seems to work correctly. But when I start the application in debug from Visual Studio, many NullReferenceExceptions are thrown, on code where it does not with .NET Framework 3.5.

The affected snippet is as follows:

```
public string ConsistencyContextKey
{
get { return Container.ConsistencyCheckRuleCo.ContextKey; }
}
```

The Property `ConsistencyCheckRuleCo` is null in the exception case.

The call to the property is via reflection. In .NET 3.5, the call comes from `System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(object)`. 
See CallStack:

[image]

In 4.5 this method was changed and now pass on to the method `[System.SecurityUtils.MethodInfoInvoke(MethodInfo, object, object[])]`.
See CallStack:

[image]

In the end of both the property gets called via `method.invoke()`.

The source for `SecurityUtils.MethodInfoInvoke` can be found [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/misc/SecurityUtils.cs,c1afb45f94a0ecec,references) and of `ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue()` [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/ReflectPropertyDescriptor.cs,34eb0f3cac05590c,references).

I know it's the source from 4.6.1, but nothing has changed and in 4.5 it's the same.

The mysterious thing is that in the `ReflectPropertyDescriptor`, there is an Try-Catch also in 3.5 and 4.5. So why does Visual Studio say there is a user-unhandled exception when the code comes to my property?

The Property is public, *not* generic and the type is visible.

Comment: Reflection was changed heavily in 4.5 to support WinRT, that does not have anything to do with this.  Just ensure that you did not ask the debugger to stop at any thrown exception.  Debug > Exceptions dialog.

Comment: I dont understand why Visual Sudio says user-unhandeld Exception. In the ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue() which is the base of the Call there is a Try-Catch-Block.

Answer (score 0):

The Reason why Visual Studio says user-unhandled Exception is because of the setting "Enable just my code". The debugger cant know that the method `ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue()` from the .NET Framework has an Try-Catch-Block. If you disable this setting the warning doesnt show anymore. I got the hint from this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751435/weird-nullreferenceexception-in-third-party-dll-c-sharp).

Another observation that I have made is that if in 3.5 a exception occurs the Exception would be forwarded. In 4.5 the exception would be thrown directly on the position where it happens. This only applies if the calling of the property is via reflection and the method `MethodInfo.Invoke()`.

I wrote a test application and on 3.5 the exception has been forwarded to the Method where i call `MethodInfo.Invoke()`. In 4.5 i got the message "user-unhandled exception". That means something has been changed in handling Exception from reflection-calls.